# Get an Image uploaded on an Image view and send it

Tags: android

I have an image already chosen and in an image view but now I would like to send the same image using a send button.How can I fetch the image so that if one clicks on the send button it choses the image and gives him a variety of options in how he can send the image.
Send button code is below

```
Button buttonSendImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
buttonSendImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);       
        picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");    
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send your picture using:"));  
    }
});Button buttonSendImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
buttonSendImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);       
        picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");    
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send your picture using:"));  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct, You can use the following code :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// Add your image URI here and send in a button click.
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

You can use a MIME type of "*/*"
```